# android studio maps occasionally not working

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, zooming

I have an app that, at first start, downloads some coordinates from the internet, save them in a database, add markers on the map, and zoom in on them.

The app works fine the first time, and the second time I run it. But on the third(and sometimes the forth) it stops adding the markers and zooming in on the map. I get no errors and even when I hard-code the coordinates that the map will zoom in on, it doesn't do it. I created a "Log.i" right before the movecamera, and one right after and they both prints to logcat, but the map doesn't zoom.

Sometimes I can hold the "home"-button exit all apps, restart my app, and it works again. But sometimes it doesn't work when I do that either.

My friend works on the same app but she doesn't have that problem on her phone, but I have the problem on both my phones. She has a higher sdk-version, can that be the reason why it works for her?

Any idea where to look for a solution?

Comment: What SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio. My phone has 4.0.3, she's got 4.4

Comment: Try this: upgrade one of your devices. Test again. If the issue goes away, we can take it from there.